# create moving text for android

Tags: android

is there any way to implanted way to create a moving text [ croos text ]

for example open meida o\player , in status bar you can see music titile will be move under buttons .

It is good idea for showing large texts  ,

how can I do this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to animate your text?
You should try see the animation resource more specifically the translate if you to create a motion

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element

Answer (score 1):

You should add some attributes to the TextView:

```
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
```

And add this line:

```
    mTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the TextView to a RelativeLayout, and adjusting the topMargin and leftMargin properties of its RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.